# Management tool for managing MongoDB sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

Is there a database management software for MongoDB that makes it easy to create a cluster, add shards, backup shards and all the complicated stuff. There are some many MongoDB clients but they are suited for single database only, and no advanced functionality like creating and managing a MongoDB sharded cluster.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current software for managing clusters and sharding for MongoDB using a GUI but you can use the likes of [mtool's mlaunch](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch) from the command line to launch clusters.